# iOS 9.3.2 - Siri Suggestions Shows Wrong Contacts

Tags: iphone, contacts, ios, siri

I have iOS 9.3.2 but this bug has been bother me for a long time so I'm sure it was present before version 9.3.2.  When I'm on the first page of apps on my home screen I swipe to the right to access "Siri Suggestions".  I love this feature and use it heavily.  But the very first contact seems to be wrong most of the time.  It always shows a dude I NEVER communicate with.  I've looked through all my texts, e-mails, etc and I have received nothing from him.  I have even deleted him from my contacts, restarted my phone, and he still appears as the first suggestion.  This usually happens 90% of the time with this one guy but a couple other times another random person I never speak to shows up.  What gives?!?! I'm sick of seeing this damn dudes face :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out!!! That person a long time ago had invited me to a Facebook event that last many many days in a row. I never declined or ignored the event and I also had my iOS calendar set to show Facebook events. I declined and ignored the event in Facebook, he still appeared, but I didn't wait long (maybe that takes a while to refresh). I was impatient so I just turned off showing my Facebook events in the calendar app all together. He finally disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

- Disabling them in Settings>General>Spotlight Search>Siri Suggestions.
- Hard restart of device. (Hold Power and Home buttons until device restarts. NOT DFU RESET)
- Re-Enable in Settings>...Siri Suggestions

Comment: Can you explain how this fixes the OP's issue?